# can anyone make me understand simply

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

```
def single(request,slug):
    pro = products.objects.get(slug=slug)
    images=productImage.objects.filter(product=pro)
    template = 'products.html'
    context = {'pro': pro,'images':images}
    return render(request, template, context)

class products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=29.99)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=False,         null=False, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class productImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):`enter code here`
        return self.product.title
```

what is the task of `pro = products.objects.get(slug=slug)` and `images=productImage.objects.filter(productt=product)`.

what is the difference between using `product.productImage_set.all` rahter than `productImage.objects.filter(product=product)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will try:

> pro = products.objects.get(slug=slug)

Get all the data from `products` where `slug` from the parameter is equals to the `slug` field present in the `products` model. As, you made `slug` a unique field, `pro` would always give only one object.

Another,

> product.productImage_set.all /  productImage.objects.filter(product=product)

What it means is, get all the data from productImage where, productImage's product object is equal to the product field. Or, products has productImage, that is one to many relation. So, you want to retrieve productImage data of that product, the returned value could be many.

*Like, your facebook profile, your profile is one but your photos could be many. So, here, you want all the photos from the profile, where profile is you.* So, *profile* is `products` and `productImage` is *photos*.

Both are same, you could use any of them. Prefer your choice. Personally, I use filter one the most.

*Tips:- It is better to write classes in `Capitalize` form in every programming language, it is suggested. Also, try to write model name in singular form, `Product` rather than `products`. Well, it is not compulsary though but highly suggested.

Comment: product.productImage_set.all / productImage.objects.filter(product=product) what this statement define?

Comment: I have made changes.

Comment: where  r u from?

Comment: ```Dumre```, ```Tanahun```... right now ... quarantine time !!!!! Else: ```Dillibazzar```. Out of topic.. Hahaha

Comment: in which grade?

Comment: Bachelor sec year!!! You understand what you were asking right?

Comment: ya i understood.